# Generate multiple webpack output files from a single script

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules

Need help with the webpack.
Project on vue, using ts and scss.
Need to generate multiple js output files that use the same source.

Now module.export looks like this:

```
module.exports {
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({ extractComments: false }),
        ],
    },
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.vue', '.json'],
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/',
        filename: 'project.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test:    /\.(ts)?$/,
                loader:  'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                    transpileOnly: true,
                },
            },
            {
                test:   /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/inline',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test:  /\.scss$/,
                oneOf: [
                    {
                        resourceQuery: /module/,
                        use:           [
                            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            {
                                loader:  'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                    modules: {
                                        localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:3]',
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            'sass-loader',
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        use: [
                            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader',
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'project.css',
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new somePlugin(
            params
          },
        ),
}
```

The output is a project js file and nodmodule scripts.
I need two output files, both created from index.js, but using different parameters for some plugin:

```
new somePlugin(
    params
    },
),
```

This plugin changes the final output file, and it is necessary to have two output files with different parameters for this plugin.

Both final scripts use the same style files and module files are not changed either, i.e. there is no need to rebuild them.

I tried to make module.exports as an array and do push, and duplicate the code, but in this case duplicate scripts of nodmodules are generated, because the output has a different filename. I would like to get rid of duplication, I couldn't come to another solution yet.